# how to run the recorded jmeter test plan

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2015-01-12 12:11:16 IST
Load time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1080
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1080
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 14: /
```

Response headers:

```
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

I am trying to execute the recorded JMeter test plan... but its showing the error as shown above. Can anyone help me how to sort it out??

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps recording issue or something connected with i.e. clash with [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).

By the way, there is an option for recording JMeter scripts right from Google Chrome browser via [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which doesn't require to worry about proxies, SSL certificates, cookies, excluding usual patterns from recording, etc. perhaps it may be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Error is `"Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException"`

This is means url is not getting passed correctly.

Solution is,

```
Remove http:// from your server/ip in your http request.
```

While running look at the request sent. it should be `http://server` and not `http://http://server`